# use vue2 cli2 import bootstrap 5 occur error

Tags: javascript, vue.js

## vue2 cli2 import bootstrap5 error

**# run dev this problem error**

```
in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (618:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
| return {
| ...this.constructor.Default,
| ...(typeof jsonConfig === 'object' ? jsonConfig : {}),
| ...(isElement(element) ? Manipulator.getDataAttributes(element) : {}),

@ ./src/main.js 6:0-19
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

But use bootstrap 4 no error
Looking for someone to help me